# Way to access stack top element to recursively compare if both stack elements are the same

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, stack, compare

How do I access the top elements of each stack so I can compare them? I used (iTop,i2Top,nTop,n2Top) because I've been testing to make this work but I can't seem to get the right output.
What am I doing wrong?

> I assumed this would work, but it's not either. Basically I want to reference the top element of stack, and compare it to the top element of stack2. Then if they are equal, pop them and do the same for the rest of the stack. At the end, if the stack is empty because all elements were the same and got popped, then it's true the stacks are the same. And push back stack 1 and stack 2.
>   Thank you

```
public Boolean sameStack(StackArray<E> s2) {
            E t1, t2;
            //E iTop = this.items[top];
            //E i2Top= s2.items[top];
            int nTop = this.top; // 
            int n2Top= s2.top;  // nTop == n2Top is true even when elements are not equal
            boolean t = true;

            if(this.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
                return t;
            }//if
            if(this.top != s2.top) {
                t = false;
                return t;
            }   
            if(this.items[top] == s2.items[s2.top]){
                t1 = this.pop();
                t2 = s2.pop();
                t = sameStack(s2);
                push(t1);
                push(t2);
            }
            else{
                t = false;
            }
            return t;
}
```

```
public class StackArray<E> {

        private int top=-1;
        private static final int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
        private E items[];

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public StackArray() {
            items = (E[]) new Object[MAX_ITEMS];
            System.out.println("Stack Created!");
        }

        public void push(E e) {
            if (isFull()==true) {
            System.out.println("Stack Full!");
            }
            else{
                top=top+1;
                items[top] = e;
            }
        }//Push

        public E pop() {
            if (isEmpty()==true) {
                System.out.println("Stack Empty!");
                }
            else{
              E e = (E) items[top];
              items[top] = null;
              top = top-1;
              return e;
            }
            return null;
        } //pop

        public boolean isFull() {
            if (top == items.length-1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } //isFull

        public boolean isEmpty(){
            if (top==-1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }//isEmpty


        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            System.out.println("Array:");
            System.out.print("{");
            for(int i = 0; i < items.length ;i++) {
                System.out.print(items[i]+" ");
        }
            System.out.print("}");
            return "";
        }//toString

        public Boolean sameStack(StackArray<E> s2) {
            E t1, t2;
            //E iTop = this.items[top];
            //E i2Top= s2.items[top];
            int nTop = this.top; // 
            int n2Top= s2.top;  // nTop == n2Top is true even when elements are not equal
            boolean t = true;

            if(this.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
                return t;
            }//if

            //This is the part I need to compare the elements
            if(nTop == n2Top) {
                t1 = this.pop()
                t2 = s2.pop();
//              t = sameStack(s2);
//              push(t1);
//              s2.push(t2);
            }   
            return t;
        }       


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            // Code reference for sameStack method
            StackArray<Integer> stack = new StackArray<Integer>();
            StackArray<Integer> stack2 = new StackArray<Integer>();

            stack.push(111);
            stack.push(222);
            stack.push(7177);
//          stack.push(40);
            stack2.push(444);
            stack2.push(555);
            stack2.push(777);
//          stack2.push(40);

            System.out.println(stack);
            System.out.println(stack2);

//          //Calling comparison method
            if (stack.sameStack(stack2) == true) {
                System.out.println("True, both stacks are equal.");
            }//if
            else {
                System.out.println("False, stacks are not equal.");
            }//else      
            System.out.println(stack);
            System.out.println(stack2);
        }//main

}//class
```

Comment: `peek` to *look*, `pop` to take.

Comment: Rather than popping everything off for a comparison create a private method which returns the array of a StackArray. The you can compare the two arrays directly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you wished to use recursion. The top version of sameStack looked like you have the right idea.

Comment: This seem like a very unusual method for checking equality. Is there a reason you wish to use recursion and popping/pushing?

Comment: @sprinter yes it's a homework assignment due tomorrow and that's the requirement I've wasted the wholeeeeeeee day on

Comment: I've suggested a method in an answer that uses recursion but doesn't pop and push values. Take a look at that to see if it satisfies the assignment

Comment: Next time you ask a question on SO you might like to include the relevant information that has come out in your comments (e.g. this is a homework assignment and you must use recursion and only peek and pop methods).

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the `items` array and compare the elements using `equals()` (not `==`).

```
public boolean sameStack(StackArray<E> s2) {
    if (this.top != s2.top) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= this.top; i++) {
        if (! this.items[i].equals(s2.items[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works, because any method of `StackArray` can access `private` members of `StackArray`, whether it's the current instance (`this`) or some other instance (e.g. `s2`).

Comment: You should also check for the case where the two stacks don't have the same number of elements.

Comment: @NomadMaker What do you think this statement does? `if (this.top != s2.top)`

Comment: @Andreas the only problem is that I am not allowed to use .equals for my assignment requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need to use recursion to test equality of your stacks then an easier method would be to pass the index to the method. Then you don't need to push and pop.

```
public boolean equals(Stack<E> other) {
    return equalsFrom(other, 0);
}

private boolean equalsFrom(Stack<E> other, int from) {
    if (from >= this.top || from >= other.top)
        return from >= this.top && from >= other.top;
    else
        return this.items[from].equals(other.items[from])
            && equalsFrom(other, from + 1);
}
```

Hopefully that method makes sense to you. The first branch of the if statement could be read as "if I've reached the end of either stack then I must have reached the end of both stacks for them to be equal". the second branch could be read as "if I haven't reach the end of either stack then the current element must be equal and the rest of the stacks must be equal for the entire stacks to be equal".

Comment: I can only use push pop and peek

Answer (score 0):

Spongebob meme Many Hours Later...........Figured it out by myself at last!

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class StackArray<E> {

        private int top=-1;
        private static final int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
        private E items[];

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public StackArray() {
            items = (E[]) new Object[MAX_ITEMS];
            System.out.println("Stack Created!");
        }

        public void push(E e) {
            if (isFull()==true) {
               System.out.println("Stack Full!");
            }
            else{
                top=top+1;
                items[top] = e;
            }
        }

        public E pop() {
             if (isEmpty()==true) {
                   System.out.println("Stack Empty!");
                }
             else{
            E e = (E) items[top];
            items[top] = null;
            top = top-1;
            return e;
             }
            return null;
        }

        public boolean isFull() {
             if (top == items.length-1) {
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty(){
             if (top==-1) {
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            System.out.println("Array:");
            System.out.print("{");
             for(int i = 0; i < items.length ;i++) {
                 System.out.print(items[i]+" ");
        }
             System.out.print("}");
            return "";
    }

        public int peek() {
            if (this.isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
            //System.out.println("items[top]"+this.items[top]);
            //System.out.println("e"+e);
            return (int) this.items[top];
        }


        public Boolean sameStack(StackArray<E> s2) {
            E t1, t2;
            boolean t = true;

            if(this.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
                return t;
            }

            if ((int) this.peek() == s2.peek()) {
                t1 = this.pop();
                t2 = s2.pop();
                t = sameStack(s2);
                this.push(t1);
                s2.push(t2);
            }
            else {
                t = false;
                return t;
            }   
            return t;           
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            // Code reference for sameStack method
           StackArray<Integer> stack = new StackArray<Integer>();
           StackArray<Integer> stack2 = new StackArray<Integer>();

            stack.push(122);
            stack.push(222);
            stack.push(3313);
            stack.push(46);
            stack2.push(122);
            stack2.push(222);
            stack2.push(3313);
            stack2.push(46);
            System.out.println(stack);
            System.out.println(stack2);

            stack.peek();
            if (stack.sameStack(stack2) == true) {
                System.out.println("They are equal");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("They are NOT equal");
            }

            System.out.println(stack);
            System.out.println(stack2);

            //Calling comparison method
           // stack.sameStack(stack2); 
        }
}
```